# Append data to post body and upload to api

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, data-access

I am calling one api with passing some parameter with including getting some file from icloud like pdf, doc, docx and call the api.

Now i am picking some file from icloud and i need to pass to api call. The issues is my selecting file ( pdf or doc ) is not converting to nsdata and bytes is coming as 0.So its not apending to my body parameters .Help me out where i m doing wrong

My code:

```
func uploadthefileToserver(){

    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.exampleurl/api"){
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let boundary:String = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        // let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 10
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let postJobData:[String:Any] = ["UserId":"107","name":"hardcodevalue"]
        var dataFile: Data = Data()
        print(fullDestPath)   ///Users/sathish/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4464E7A8-0F38-4802-B645-19721D251054/data/Containers/Data/Application/714B1B8E-5872-42B9-B963-B0C51C9403D7/Documents/NewFileiCloud/iOS.DOCX"
        do{
            dataFile = try NSData.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fullDestPath, isDirectory: true)) as Data
            print(dataFile)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
        if(dataFile==nil)  { return; }
        print(dataFile) //0 bytes
        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: postJobData, filePathKey: "Resume", FileData: dataFile as NSData , boundary: boundary) as Data
        print(postJobData)
        print(dataFile)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in


            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }else if let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                print("****** response data = \(responseString)")
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                    print(json)

                    let status = json!["Success"] as! String
                    let errMessage = json!["Message"] as? String
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        if status == "1"{
                            print(errMessage)

                        }else{
                            print(errMessage)
                        }
                    }

                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }; task.resume()
    }
}
```

Not sure where i am doing wrong. I put some print functions for the referance.

Main parts :

```
dataFile = try NSData.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:
fullDestPath, isDirectory: true)) as Data

request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: postJobData,
filePathKey: "Resume", FileData: dataFile as NSData , boundary:
boundary) as Data
```

Thanks

Update :

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

        print("url = \(urls)")
        filePathUrl = urls
        print(filePathUrl)
        for urll in filePathUrl{
            filepath = filePathUrl[0] as! URL
            print(filepath)
            filePathString = filepath.path
            urlstr = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePathString).lastPathComponent!
            print(urlstr)
            // Data object to fetch weather data
            do {
                let weatherData = try NSData(contentsOf: filepath, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
                print(weatherData)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        let destPath:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        print(destPath, "\n")
        documentDir = destPath[0] as? NSString
        let filePath = documentDir?.appendingPathComponent("NewFileiCloud") as! NSString

      //  if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath as String){

            do {
               // try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: filePath as String, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
                fullDestPath = filePath.appendingPathComponent(urlstr)
                print(fullDestPath!) ///Users/sathish/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4464E7A8-0F38-4802-B645-19721D251054/data/Containers/Data/Application/E41634D7-681A-4C09-B3EF-5782CECCF4B0/Documents/NewFileiCloud/filke.pdf
                do{
                    try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: filePathString!, toPath: fullDestPath)
                }catch{
                    print("\n")
                    print(error)
                }
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
       // }

      // ------- This is the path of the application stored filepath -------------- //

        filePathLabel.text = fullDestPath

// ------------------- ---------------------------------//
// Read a file content
        //     fileContent = fileManager.contents(atPath: fullDestPath as String ) as! NSData
        //       print(fileContent)

        uploadthefileToserver()
    }

 func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: Any]?, filePathKey: String?, FileData: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {

        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string:"--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        return body

        let filename = fullDestPath
        let mimetype = "pdf/docx/text"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(FileData as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }
```

Comment: /Documents/NewFileiCloud/iOS.DOCX , How did u add that iOS.DOCX to documents folder? Can u show that code  ?

Comment: i added through simulator

Comment: U have to show the code. How u are trying to store .docx from icloud to documents directory.

Comment: @McDonal_11 I have updated..even my data is nil. its not at all appending to the body parameters

Comment: Did u try this Robin ? Any update?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do,

1. Convert PDFURL to Data
2. Convert Data to .PDF
3. Storing that .PDF in Doc.Dir.
4. Retriving that .PDF from Doc.Dir and Pass to Server.

For the above task, you have to create folder `NewFileiCloud` in `Doc.Dir`. Then, convert `pdfUrl` to `data` and write that data to `.pdf` file, and then, get that `.pdf` path from `doc.dir` and convert that into `Data` and pass to `server`.

I have did sample for you. This will satisfy you.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // I have did sample for you by taking .pdf from bundle.
    if let pathPDF = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf") {

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/NewFileiCloud"))
        do {
            //You have to create directory with above name.
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent("reader.pdf")

            //YOUR PDF URL [pathPDF [my bundle path, you have to give your URL]] to DATA
            let pdfData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathPDF))  

            // WRITE ITS CONTENT to Doc.Dir.
            try pdfData.write(to: destinationURLForFile, options:.atomic)

            //ASSIGN PATH TO GLOBAL URL VARIABLE
            fullPAth = destinationURLForFile


            print("conclude     ", destinationURLForFile)

            uploadToServer()

        }
        catch(let error){
            print(error)
        }

    }
}


func uploadToServer() {

    .....

    do {

        // Here you can get PDF contents as Data.
        // With this Data, you can pass to Server Side.
        let pdfPOSTData = try Data(contentsOf: fullPAth!)
    }
    catch let e{
        print("Catch_Not_worlk    ",  e)
    }

    ......
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185093/discussion-on-answer-by-mcdonal-11-append-data-to-post-body-and-upload-to-api).